# Python script to match actual start of line ignoring tabs and spaces

Tags: javascript, python, regex, pattern-matching, gedit

I think my question is pretty much self-explanatory, but still I would post an example for more clarity.

I have following fully working script to comment/uncomment the lines in a Javascript file opened in the Gedit editor.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import StringIO
block = sys.stdin.read()
block = StringIO.StringIO(block)
msg = ''
for line in block:
    if "//~" in line:
        line = line.replace('//~','')
        msg = "All lines in selection uncommented"
    else:
        line = "//~" + line
        msg = "All lines in selection commented"
    sys.stdout.write(line)
exit(msg)
```

Now I want to put `//~` in front of the actual start of line (not spaces or tabs but when really line starts i.e. characters and strings).

If I do this with regex module like below then it adds `//~` twice, means to both start of line and actual start of line.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import StringIO
import re
block = sys.stdin.read()
block = StringIO.StringIO(block)
msg = ''
for line in block:
    if "//~" in line:
        line = re.sub(r"(\s*)(\S.*)", r"\1//~\2", line)
        line = line.replace('//~','')
        msg = "All lines in selection uncommented"
    else:
        line = re.sub(r"(\s*)(\S.*)", r"\1//~\2", line)
        line = "//~" + line
        msg = "All lines in selection commented"
    sys.stdout.write(line)
exit(msg)
```

How can I do that with/without Regex in python ?

Comment: To remove them just use `line.lstrip()`, in an RE start it with `r'^\s*'`

Comment: Check this :--- https://regex101.com/r/hU4vO7/4

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar That doesn't match any of the indented lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex replacements to do this. For example, this line of code should do what you want

```
line = re.sub(r"^(\s*)(\S.*)", r"\1//~\2", line)
```

This regex matches 0 or more space characters [(\s*)], then matches the rest of the string [(\S.*)]. It then replaces this with the 1st capturing group [\1], the spaces, then the two slashes [//~], then the rest of the string [\2].

Comment: This doesn't work in my above mentioned python script, even after I add `import re` to my script.

Comment: `>>> line = '    if "//~" in line:'
>>> re.sub(r"(\s*)(\S.*)", r"\1//~\2", line)  
'    //~if "//~" in line:'`
Works for me

Comment: Ok, it works now, but it adds `//~` two times. One at the start of line and other at the actual start of line.

Comment: What's the actual start of the line

Comment: I suggest you please read my question better, I have mentioned that `actual start of line` is line without tabs/spaces in the starting point, means where actual character starts. Also I have updated my question with latest code I have tried and prints duplicate `//~`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115791/discussion-between-natecat-and-vicky-dev).

Comment: Sorry, the chat site is blocked in my office can we continue here for time-being and then remove unnecessary comments ?

Comment: delete `        line = "//~" + line`

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it works, fine, no need to change in the `if` condition `block` right ?

Comment: Please update your answer and also add a little explanation and break-up about regex you have used. I will mark it accepted then.